# Use template fields in BaseSensorOperator for SFTPSensor

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to add `{{ prev_execution_date }}` and `{{ execution_date }}` to my custom SFTPSensor. Below is my code:

```
class SFTPSensor(BaseSensorOperator):

    template_fields = ('path','prev_execution_date','execution_date')

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, path, prev_execution_date, execution_date, sftp_conn_id='sftp_default',*args, **kwargs):
        super(EETSensor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.path = path
        self.hook = None
        self.sftp_conn_id = sftp_conn_id
        self.prev_execution_date = prev_execution_date
        self.execution_date = execution_date

    def poke(self, context): # pylint: disable=unused-argument
        self.hook = SFTPHook(self.sftp_conn_id)
        self.log.info('Poking for %s', self.path)
        try:

            files_list = self.hook.list_directory(self.path)
            files_desc = self.hook.describe_directory(self.path)

            self.log.info("PREVIOUS EXECUTION DATE {}".format(self.prev_execution_date))

            self.log.info("CURRENT EXECUTION DATE {}".format(self.execution_date))

            return len(files_list) > 0
        except IOError as e: # pylint: disable=invalid-name
            if e.errno != SFTP_NO_SUCH_FILE:
                raise e
            return False
        finally:
            self.hook.close_conn()

sftp_sensor = SFTPSensor(task_id='my_sensor',
                         path='/my_directory/',
                         prev_execution_date='{{ prev_execution_date }}',
                         execution_date='{{ execution_date }}',
                         sftp_conn_id='source_eet_conn',
                         poke_interval=60,
                         dag=dag)
```

Yet, my log is still displaying :

> [2021-01-06 13:10:21,207] {{main.py:118}} INFO - PREVIOUS EXECUTION DATE {{ prev_execution_date }}
> [2021-01-06 13:10:21,207] {{main.py:120}} INFO - CURRENT EXECUTION DATE {{ execution_date }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified a bit your code to make it runnable.
However short of fixing the wrong class name when calling supper (`EETSensor` in your example) I couldn't reproduce the issue that you are describing.

```
class SFTPSensor(BaseSensorOperator):
    template_fields = ('path','prev_execution_date','execution_date')

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, path, prev_execution_date, execution_date, sftp_conn_id='sftp_default', *args, **kwargs):
        super(SFTPSensor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.path = path
        self.hook = None
        self.sftp_conn_id = sftp_conn_id
        self.prev_execution_date = prev_execution_date
        self.execution_date = execution_date

    def poke(self, context): # pylint: disable=unused-argument
        self.hook = SFTPHook(self.sftp_conn_id)
        self.log.info('Poking for %s', self.path)
        try:

            files_list = None
            files_desc = None

            self.log.info("PREVIOUS EXECUTION DATE {}".format(self.prev_execution_date))

            self.log.info("CURRENT EXECUTION DATE {}".format(self.execution_date))

            return len(files_list) > 0
        except IOError as e: # pylint: disable=invalid-name
            if e.errno != SFTP_NO_SUCH_FILE:
                raise e
            return False
        finally:
            self.hook.close_conn()


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 3, 24, 2, 0, 0),
}


dag = DAG(
    'sftp',
     schedule_interval="@once",
     default_args=default_args)


sftp_sensor = SFTPSensor(task_id='my_sensor',
                         path='/my_directory/',
                         prev_execution_date='{{ prev_execution_date }}',
                         execution_date='{{ execution_date }}',
                         sftp_conn_id='sftp_default',
                         poke_interval=60,
                         dag=dag)
```

You can use this template for the desired functionality.

[image: Render]

[image: Log]

Comment: Oh yes `EETSensor` I forgot to change that :P But I managed to get the macros works. Apparently the code I showed, works just fine. Thank you!